# How to Integrate skrill with flutter?

Tags: flutter, payment-gateway, skrill

I know how to Integrate stripe with flutter. But i want to know how to Integrate Skrill payment gateway with my flutter app.

Answer (score -1):

if you want to integrate any platforms or services into your platform, you have to go to the bottom of the official web-site and find the links through the section **API** or **Developer guide**. I found this [link](https://developer-psd2.skrill.com/) for your reference.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).